# Summing elements of the array - MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

So I start out with this code which builds an array of 20 elements - integers 1 to 20.

```
# initialise array
.text
main: la $t0,array
 li $s2,1
 li $s4,20
loop: bgt $s2, $s4, end
sw $s2,0($t0)
addi $s2, $s2, 1
addi $t0, $t0, 4
j loop
end:
 li $v0,10
 syscall
 .data
nl: .asciiz "\n"
 .word 255 # give a recognisable bit pattern
array: .space 80
```

Now what I'm supposed to do is create another array size 20 and have each element be the sum of all preceding elements of array one (the one in given code, called array). Now this is what I came up with so far:

```
# initialise array
    .text
main:   la $t0,array
    la $t1,sum
    li $s2,1
        li $s4,20
loop:   bgt $s2, $s4, end
    sw $zero,0($t0) 
    add $s3,$s2,$t0
    sw $s3,0($t1)
        sw $s2,0($t0)
    addi $s2, $s2, 1
    addi $t0, $t0, 4
    addi $t1, $t1, 4
        j loop
end:
    li  $v0, 1 
    lw $s3, 0($t1) 
    add $a0, $s3, $zero  # print final value in sum
    syscall
        li $v0,10
        syscall
       .data
nl:      .asciiz "\n"
    .word 255 # give a recognisable bit pattern
array:  .space 80
sum:    .space 80
```

Now at the end I want to print the value of last element of new array (sum) and for a 20 element array it should be equal 210 (sum of all previous integers) but at this point I'm getting 0 and I genuinely no longer know where the problem lies (now I've only started doing anything with mips and I have very little knowledge of anything).

Comment: Why do you have 3 `sw` instructions inside your 2nd loop?  The `sw` of `$zero` is dead because you always store a different value to the same location later in the same loop.  Have you tried single-stepping through your code with the debugger built-in to your MIPS simulator?

Comment: Also, comment your code, especially if you want others to help. PS: your `$t1` is always pointing past the end, so printing stuff from there will never make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you leave the loop, `$t1` is pointing to one past the end of the `sum[]` array.  So use `lw $s3, -4($t1)`.  (Also, why not load directly into `$a0` instead of loading into `$s3` and then copying to `$a0`?)

Or better, omit the load entirely because you still have the last element you stored sitting in `$s3` from the loop body.  So keep the `add $a0, $s3, $zero  # print final value in sum` and drop the `lw`.

---

Once you fix that, you will notice another bug: you've been setting `s3 = i + &array[i]` with `add $s3,$s2,$t0`.  You actually want to do `s3 += s2` with `add $s3, $s3, $s2`.

---

Also, you're using the `$s` registers without saving/restoring them.  This is ok because you exit with a syscall instead of returning from `main`, but any function that returns should do so with all the `$s0-7` registers having their original values.  [MIPS registers](http://www.cs.uwm.edu/classes/cs315/Bacon/Lecture/HTML/ch05s03.html).

The easiest way to do this is not to use those registers at all.  Use `$t0-9` and/or `$a0-4` / `$v0-1` as temporaries.